# Should I bake the Jenkins config file for each Jenkins master into our custom Jenkins Docker image?

Tags: docker, jenkins

It's a bit uncomfortable for us to have a Jenkins Docker image that is used for 4 different Jenkins Master Servers with a different Jenkins configuration.

We use an environment variable that loads the correct Jenkins xml configuration file, but every configuration change we do, has to be manually baked back into the Docker image or else the change will be lost of the next container restart, etc.

Jenkins is obviously not a perfect cloud-native Docker image candidate, but we have no choice. What would be the proper way to handle this? Completely exclude overwriting the Jenkins configuration file if there is already 1 present?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your question is missing a lot of context necessary to give a meaningful answer, but without more information, I would would give a cautious "yes, you should package your Jenkins configuration with your Docker images."

For reference, here's a blog post detailing how one admin deploys Jenkins via Docker + Kubernetes + Helm.  One of the goals explicitly stated for this project was to deploy and version the Docker image as a whole, including configuration, plugins, etc. (see point 2.):

> The Shape
>
> After a bunch of research, the overall shape of the goal came together
>   fairly quickly. We’ll go through each of these in excruciating detail
>   later on, but to start let’s break it down into bullet points:
>
> 1. Deployed on Kubernetes, because this is the way we’re trying to move everything.
> 2. Build a container image containing Jenkins, all the plugins, and configuration.
> 3. se Helm for managing the deployment (and rollback if needed).
> 4. Manage the configuration via Jenkins groovy as much as possible.
> 5. Use the “organization folder” system in Jenkins to auto-detect projects.
> 6. Use shared pipeline libraries to keep the per-repository config low.
> 7. Build a container image for the cookbook testing environment that has all needed gems pre-installed.
> 8. Work out a way to test cookbooks on top of Kubernetes pods.

The fact that you have 4 different Jenkins instances doesn't really change anything, it just means you have 4 different services to manage and deploy to independently.  You can have all of these images inherit from a base Jenkins image if you wish to reduce a little bit of duplication.